# Splitting a column in a data frame over several columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm loading a csv file that has two columns: `date` and `tags`. `tags` contains a **list of tags** like so:

```
date,tags
2021-09-08,"#foo, #bar"
2021-09-10,"#bar"
2021-09-15,"#bar, #baz"
2021-09-22,"#bar"
```

loading it with pandas will result in a data frame where all tags are put into one column like so:

```
        date            tags
0 2021-09-08      #foo, #bar
1 2021-09-10            #bar
2 2021-09-15      #bar, #baz
3 2021-09-22            #bar
```

So, how do I create from this a data frame, a data frame where each tag is separated into their own column:

```
        date    foo   bar    baz
0 2021-09-08  True   True  False
1 2021-09-10  False  True  False
2 2021-09-15  False  True   True
3 2021-09-22  False  True  False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with convert `0,1` to boolean and add to `date` column by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df[['date']].join(df['tags'].str.get_dummies(', ').astype(bool))
print(df)
         date  #bar   #baz   #foo
0  2021-09-08  True  False   True
1  2021-09-10  True  False  False
2  2021-09-15  True   True  False
3  2021-09-22  True  False  False
```

If need remove `#` add `rename` with custom function:

```
f = lambda x: x.lstrip('#')
df = df[['date']].join(df['tags'].str.get_dummies(', ').astype(bool).rename(columns=f))
print(df)
         date   bar    baz    foo
0  2021-09-08  True  False   True
1  2021-09-10  True  False  False
2  2021-09-15  True   True  False
3  2021-09-22  True  False  False
```